# Is there any way to measure how the work is being spread among the cores?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I'm wondering, is there any reliable way of seeing (or measuring) how well my app's work is being distributed to the cores in a server?  The only (very unscientific) options that come to mind are:

1. "eyeballing" the CPU graphs in the task manager
2. having the app constantly write out `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` to the console as each piece of work is done

Surely there are better options?

**Background:** 
My app listens for incoming packets, does some in-memory work, and writes stuff to a database.
My target platform is a Windows Server machine with four cores.  The first version of my app was clearly using one core heavily, and the other three were mostly idle.  I deployed a second version using `Task.Factory.StartNew()` in an attempt to distribute the work among the other cores each time I receive a packet.  It now looks like ALL cores are busier than the single core was in my first app.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537632.aspx

Comment: @RobertHarvey - excellent!  Thank you.  If you want to post that as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2):

> The Concurrency Visualizer enables you to see how your
>   multithreaded application interacts with itself, the hardware, the
>   operating system, and other processes on the computer. These views
>   provide graphical, tabular, and textual data that shows the temporal
>   relationships between the threads in your program and the system as a
>   whole.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537632.aspx